# A polynomial is irreducible in a splitting field of another polynomial

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

Suppose that $E$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $f(x)=x^3-2$. We want to show using Galois theory that $g(x)=x^2-5$ is irreducible in $E[x]$.

Here is what I have so far. Assume for contradiction that $g(x)$ is reducible in $E[x]$. $g(x)$ has roots $\sqrt 5$ and $-\sqrt 5$. Then we have a subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ in $E$. We have that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\beta) \subset E$. I then hope to use The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory to reach a contradiction using the degrees of the extensions although I am not sure how I would go about this?

Comment: Would it suffice to just show $\sqrt 5 \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$? Then we get $-\sqrt 5 \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$ as a result?

Comment: Yes, $a\in K$ implies $-a\in K$, because $K$ is a field.

Comment: For this, if we assume $\sqrt 5 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$ then we have $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 5) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$. Then we can use the tower rule to get $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 5)] = \frac{6}{2} = 3$. I am not sure how to get a contradiction from here.

Comment: You can use Galois theory to classify all subextensions of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ over $\Bbb Q$. So first determine all subgroups of the Galois group of $x^3-2$ and then determine its fixed fields.

Comment: For your informtion, the splitting field of $E$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,i\sqrt{3})$. The imaginary unit $i\notin E$. Given that you have read about the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, you should follow the program outline by Dietrich Burde. Hint: Show that $E$ has a single quadratic subfield.